# How to initialize a new multidimensional object array with a lower bound of 1?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Simple question really - my solution would be far more simple if I can achieve this.

I know you can use:

```
 Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new int[] { 1 }, new int[] { 1 });
```

To create a multidimensional System.Array of type object with a specific size and lower bound.

However I need an object[,] that has a lower bound of [1,1].

Is this possible? Or is there a way to cast to the object while keeping the boundary?

Comment: Did you consider `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new int[] { 1, 1 }, new int[] { 1, 1 });`?

Comment: I did, actually - however how do I cast that from System.Array to object[,]?

Comment: Oh it worked this time... :S lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
(object[,])Array.CreateInstance(typeof(object), new int[] { 1, 1 }, new int[] { 1, 1 });
```

Thanks for the nudge! :)

P.S: How I failed to make it work:
I think I foolishly tried using {1, 1} without the cast and then {1} with the cast. :S